# Calling ASP.NET Web API with ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, webforms

I am trying to learn Web APi in asp.net by this tutorial :
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/02/23/using-asp-net-web-api-with-asp-net-web-forms.aspx

I have a website that is working fine , Now i want to integrate WEB API .I created simple WEB API Controller class  "Controller" , put RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute in Application_Start() in global.asax and then tried to call Api, but i am not getting data as output ..

this is controller class

```
public class Controller : ApiController
{
    // GET api/<controller>
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/<controller>/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/<controller>
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT api/<controller>/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/<controller>/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

Glogal Asax file:

```
<script runat="server">

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
         RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "DefaultApi",
             routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
             defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
         );

    }

    void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        //  Code that runs on application shutdown

    }

    void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs

    }

    void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Code that runs when a new session is started

    }

    void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Code that runs when a session ends. 
        // Note: The Session_End event is raised only when the sessionstate mode
        // is set to InProc in the Web.config file. If session mode is set to StateServer 
        // or SQLServer, the event is not raised.

    }

</script>
```

and trying to call

http://localhost:56497/api/values/
http://localhost:56497/api/

but it gives error :

```
<Error>
<Message>
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:56497/api/controller/'.
</Message>
<MessageDetail>
No type was found that matches the controller named 'controller'.
</MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

What is something that I am missing ?

Answer (score 1):

`Controller` name for controller is not the best choice. Convention is that controllers should have names like `SomethingController`. Since you are calling it with `/api/values`, I think you should have named it `ValuesController`:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
```

By the way it looks like the tutorial you referenced uses exactly the same name.